# Not able to upload the file more the 50 KB in WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

Below give the web.config file in WCF service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
          <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
              <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                <filter type="" />
              </add>
              <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                <filter type="" />
              </add>
            </listeners>
          </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
          <add initializeData="c:\tfslatest\entermarkets\project specific\psbd\trunk\smartincident\pss.web.services.internal\web_tracelog.svclog"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </sharedListeners>
      </system.diagnostics>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        <!--                                  -->
        <!-- *** DATABASE ***                 -->
        <!--                                  -->
        <add key="Db Timeout Seconds" value="200" />
        <add key="Enable SMS" value="true" />
        <add key="Enable Notification" value="true" />
        <add key="K2 Server" value="EM-K2" />
        <add key="Forgot Password External Url" value="http://localhost/PSS.Web/ResetPassword.aspx?id=" />
        <add key="Incident Mobile Download Url" value="http://localhost/PSS.Web/DownloadApp.aspx?id=" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>

        <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true" />

        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" 
        useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
        executionTimeout="14400"   />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>    

        <bindings>

          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="AttachmentService"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
           maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >

              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                   maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                   maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INotificationService" />
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://localhost/Utility.Notification.Service/NotificationService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INotificationService" contract="INotificationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_INotificationService" />
          <endpoint address="http://localhost/PSS.Web.Services.Internal/AttachmentService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="AttachmentService"
              contract ="IAttachmentService">
          </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />    
      </system.serviceModel>
      <!--<security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>-->
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
          -->
        <!--<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>-->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" maxUrl="2147483648" maxQueryString="2147483648" />
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
      </system.webServer>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Conn_PSBDDb" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=192.168.0.100:1521/orcl;USER ID=PSBD;Password=password*1;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

This is Server Side Config Files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
   -->
<configuration>

  <appSettings>  

    <!--                                  -->
    <!-- *** PLUG-IN CONFIGURATION ***    -->
    <!--                                  -->  

    <!-- Plug-In Collection -->
    <!-- Format for each entry is <Type>#<Assembly> -->
    <add key="AD Authentication PlugIn Evaluation List" value="PSS.AD.Adapters.NonMemberServer.NonMemberServerManager#PSS.AD.Adapters.NonMemberServer" />
    <add key="Login Url" value="http://localhost/PSS.Web/Login.aspx" />
    <add key="Forgot Password External Url" value="http://localhost/PSS.Web/ResetPassword.aspx?id=" />
    <add key="Incident Mobile Download Url" value="http://localhost/PSS.Web/DownloadApp.aspx?id=" />
    <add key="PSS Url" value="http://localhost/PSS.Web/" />

    <!--<add key="Templates Url" value="C:\TFS\EnterMarkets\Project Specific\PSBD\Trunk\SmartIncident\PSS.Web.Services.Internal\bin\MessageTemplates" />-->
    <add key="Templates Url" value="\\192.168.0.243\psbd\PSS.Web.Services.Internal\bin\MessageTemplates" />

    <add key="Hyper Pay URL" value="https://test.oppwa.com/" />
    <add key="Hyper Pay UserId" value="8a829417527905e80152794f55950197" />
    <add key="Hyper Pay Password" value="e2XRrKJa" />
    <add key="Hyper Pay EntityId" value="8a829417527905e80152794f8af10199" />


    <add key="Hyper Pay PaymentType" value="DB" />

    <!--For testing it must be 'EXTERNAL' else change to 'INTERNAL' as per documentation-->
    <add key="Hyper Pay Test Mode" value="EXTERNAL" />

    <!--                                  -->
    <!-- *** DATABASE ** *                -->
    <!--                                  -->
    <add key="Db Timeout Seconds" value="200" />

    <!--                                  -->
    <!-- *** LOGGING ***                  -->
    <!--                                  -->
    <add key="EnableLogging" value="false" />
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="C:\Temp\Logs\PSS.Web.log" />

    <add key="Enable SMS" value="true" />

    <add key="Enable Notification" value="true" />

    <add key="Domain Name" value="coruscant" />

    <add key="EnableExamExecution" value="false" />


    <!--
            If "EnableLogging" is set to true, this integer
            specifies the max size in bytes which the log file can be until it will
            be purged on next write to the log file
            Default value: 100000000
        -->

    <add key="Attachment Plug-In List" value="PSS.Core.Attachment.Adapters.FileServer.FileServerManager#PSS.Core.Attachment.Adapters.FileServer" />

    <add key="MaxLogFileSize" value="100000000" />

    <!-- Event Log Logging -->
    <add key="EventLogSourceName" value="PSS.Web" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    <add key="language" value="ar" />
    <add key="FilestorePath" value="C:\Filestore\" />

    <!--Phisical Paths-->
    <add key="C:\TFS\EnterMarkets\Project Specific\PSBD\Trunk\SmartIncident\PSS.Web" value="" />
    <add key="UploadedFiles" value="C:\TFS\EnterMarkets\Project Specific\PSBD\Trunk\SmartIncident\PSS.Web\UploadedFiles\" />
    <!--/Phisical Paths-->

  </appSettings>

  <system.web> 
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150"/>

  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />        
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn_PSBDDb" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=192.168.0.100:1521/ORCL;USER ID=PSBD;Password=password*1;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />

  </connectionStrings><!---->

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" maxUrl="2147483648" maxQueryString="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="BundleModule" />22
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>-->
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <!--
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />

      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" /> -->
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <!--
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ipa" mimeType="application/octet-stream" /> -->

    </staticContent>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>    
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IADService" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkFlowService" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INotificationService" />
        <!--<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" />-->
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.245/PSS.AD.Web.Services/ADService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IADService" contract="ADWebService.IADService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IADService" />
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.242/PSS.Web.Services.Internal/WorkFlowService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkFlowService" contract="PSSWorkFlowService.IWorkFlowService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkFlowService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/Utility.Notification.Service/NotificationService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INotificationService" contract="INotificationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_INotificationService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/PSS.Web.Services.Internal/AttachmentService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" contract="AttachmentsService.IAttachmentService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I am unable to upload more the 50KB file, less than 50kb is working fine the exception I am getting is (The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.). Any help could be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: If IIS rejects a request based on document or message size I believe it returns a 404.13. Have been able to validate whether it call the service endpoint is actually called?

Comment: Yes, service end point is actually called when size is less 50kb. If there wouldn't be a problem with size then I think less then 50kb also should not work.

Comment: This web.config posted above is the client config right? And what about the service config? What is the service endpoints configuration?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Please see my edited post with server side configs.

Comment: I could notice that you don't have `services` tag under `system.serviceModel`, so your service are using default values for `webHttpBinding`. Add a `<webHttpBinding>` to your server config, it can be equals your client configuration but without a name. Let me know if worked.